# remove an object from an array without using arraylist

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked but I couldn't use the solutions of it to do what I want to do
My problem is every time I call from the function and enter an Id it always tells me that the id was removed even if I entered an id that was never entered it still prints the same
any tip and help would be appreciated :)
Note: I don't want to use ArrayList in it
here is my code :

```
public Members[] deleteMembers(String id) {
        if (id == null)
            return member;
        Members[] copyId = new Members[member.length - 1];

        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < member.length; i++) {
            if (member[i].getId().equals(id)) {

                continue;
            }
        
            copyId[k++] = member[i];
        }

        return copyId;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your problem with that code? It's unclear for me at least what's the issue here.

Comment: when i run it and enter a member after that when i go to delete it by using this function it gives me and error telling me that the index is -1

Comment: You're trying to copy every element from your `member` array to your shorter `copyId` array, except the ones with the given id. If none of them have the given id, then there is not enough space in your target array.

Comment: You don't want to use an ArrayList, how about a Stream? Is that allowed?

Comment: Hi, why you don't use: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils? It have functions like contains, add, indexOf and remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one problem. Do not forget, that array could not have an item with a given `id`.

```java
public static Member[] deleteMember(String id, Member[] members) {
    if (id == null || members == null)
        return members;

    int pos = findMemberPos(id, members);

    if (pos == -1)
        return members;

    Member[] arr = new Member[members.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < members.length; i++)
        if (i != pos)
            arr[i] = members[j++];

    return arr;
}

private static int findMemberPos(String id, Member[] members) {
    for (int i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(members[i].getId()))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
    public Members[] deleteMembers(String id) {
        if (id == null)
            return member;

        if (!doArrayContainsId(id)) {
            return member;
        }
        Members[] copyId = new Members[member.length - 1];

        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < member.length; i++) {
            if (member[i].getId().equals(id)) {
                continue;
            }

            copyId[k++] = member[i];
        }

        return copyId;
    }

    public boolean doArrayContainsId(String id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean doArrayContainsId = false;

        for (Members members : member) {
            if (members.getId().equals(id)) {
                doArrayContainsId = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return doArrayContainsId;
    }
```

Btw you should try to name your classes a bit better like Member instead of Members since one object is one member and array or list of them should be called members